# Toggle open a select form element by clicking the label (using react, javascript or css, either way)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown with a floating label, it doesn't toggle unless I click on the form element itself, clicking on the label it is not working, is there a way to do this either in react, javascript (I read no), or CSS.

Thank you

```
<select id="age" name="age">
    <option disabled></option>
    <option value="1">0-10</option>
    <option value="2">10-15</option>
    <option value="3">15-20</option>
    <option value="4">20+</option>
</select>
<label className="animated-label" htmlFor="age">
    Age
</label>
```

Using the label for it doesn't work. Is there anyfunction that I could use to manually toggle the dropdown open programatically

Answer (score -1):

Sharing your code with us would help us understand more about a problem you are facing.

The solution here should be very simple on your label tag add attribute "for" so it is consistent with the select menu id.
Example:

```
<label for="dropdown-menu">
    My dropdown
    <select id="dropdown-menu">
      <option>...</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Comment: Hi @Vladan Grubo Paunovic It doesn't work, I added my code above. Thank you. I need to have the label underneath

Comment: @user3808307 can you please share your code with my updates so I can debug it for you?

Comment: one of the solutions I used for a multiple select was to add pointer-events:none to the label, I had one of those animated labels that take the place of the placeholder, it is not fully cross browser but it was enough for me, then I had another example without that, I will look for it and share the code during the weekend

Comment: Clicking the label does not open the select, it just focuses it. Tested only in Chrome and Firefox.